# Getting checkout button to navigate to checkout page

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, import

I am working in Eclipse and struggling with a certain step in my assignment so any help would be appriciated because I actually dont know how to do it even though I realise how glaringly simple it probably is...

I have a shopping app and I have created my CheckoutActivity... now... it needs to start when the user clicks the checkout button in my CartActivity.

I need to add code in the ocCreate method of my CartActivity (which I will provide below) that specifies the listener for the Checkout button. then I need to define a button variable named btn inside the onCreate. I then need to assign the button element from the view using the id that you specified in my activity_cart.xml layout.

All I have so far is this... and I have no idea what to do...

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            //I cant figure out how to get it to start the CheckoutActivity
        }
    });
```

Just in case you need to see the code I have so far... here is the code I have for my cartActivty

```
    package uk.ac.uk.st265.shopper;

    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle.Control;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class CartActivity extends Activity {

    CartListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_price); // its not in
                                                                    // XML
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        text.setText("£"
                + df.format(((ShopperApp) getApplication()).getCartTotal()));

        adapter = new CartListAdapter(this);
        ListView cartList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        adapter.setItemList(((ShopperApp) getApplication()).cart);
        cartList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        //work5ass2part6

        //btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //public void onClick(final View v) {
                // I cant figure out how to get it to start the CheckoutActivity
            //}
        //});
    }


    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class CartListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final Context context;
        private List<Product> itemList;

        public CartListAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        public void setItemList(List<Product> itemList) {
            // this.itemList = itemList;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View cell = convertView;

            if (cell == null) {
                // get layout from mobile xml
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                        .getLayoutInflater();
                cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_cart, parent, false);
            }

            Product p = itemList.get(position);

            // set value into text view according to position
            TextView textView = (TextView) cell
                    .findViewById(R.id.product_title);
            textView.setText(p.getProductName());

            textView = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.product_info);
            textView.setText("Price " + p.getPrice());

            // set value into image view according to position
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) cell
                    .findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            // clear the image
            imgView.setImageDrawable(null);
            // and load from the network
            p.loadImage(imgView, 54, 54);

            return cell;

        }

        public List<Product> getItemList() {
            return itemList;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
        case R.id.show_cart:
            // Create the intent for the cart activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

and here is the code I have so far on my CheckoutActivity:

```
    package uk.ac.uk.st265.shopper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class CheckoutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.checkout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
//  myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //if you want to pass parameter
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```